# How do I calculate the percentage one number is between a min and max?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is simple obvious math but my brain isn't working.

a = 70

b = 20

c = 120

d = 0.5

I know `a` is 50%(`d`) of the distance between `b` and `c`, but how do I calculate it?

In my head I know 50 is obviously 50% between 0 and 100 and if I add 20 to each number in the range I stay at 50%, but if I just know `a`, `b`, and `c` I'm for some reason blanking out on how to get `d`.

Comment: $70$ is the mean : $\frac{70}{20+120} = 0.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have $\min < x < \max$ to find what percentage one number $x$ is between a min and a max you take $$\frac{x - \min}{\max - \min}\times 100\%.$$  For example, we can say that $70$ is $50\%$ of the way between $20$ and $120$ because $$\frac{70 - 20}{120 - 20}\times 100\% = \frac{50}{100}\times 100\% = 50\%.$$  As another example, we can say that $15$ is $20\%$ of the way between $5$ and $55$ because $$\frac{15 - 5}{55 - 5}\times 100\% = \frac{10}{50}\times 100\% = 20\%.$$